# Npm doesn't work because of PyCharm

Tags: npm, pycharm

I have a strange error when I try to run an `npm start`
Here it is:

```
teddy@***:~/***$ npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start /Users/teddy/***
> electron .

The file /Applications/PyCharm.app does not exist.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/teddy/.npm/_logs/2018-03-25T09_57_37_106Z-debug.log
```

I removed pycharm because the script launched pycharm instead of executing the command line.

Can someone help me fixing this?
Thank you

Comment: Your example says `npm start` and not `npm install`.

Comment: It produces the same error